# If I click on, the popup shows but the values didn't showing in Edge

Tags: javascript

Currently, we have to start using Edge starts from 15 June according to Microsoft but there is something strange happens in our website. That is if I click on, the popup shows but the following values didn't show up. That only happens in Edge but trying in IE mode, it shows all, and working really well, is there any way to fix it? I will insert screenshot for more details.
This one is in IE and after history.php, you can see the values.:

Same link is open in both browser and only Edge is causing error.

Below is JavaScript.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rtio').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var na = $(this).text();
        if(na != 0){
            myWindow = window.open("history.php?id="+id, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=300,left=250,width=1000,height=400");
        } else {
            alert('no data available');
        }
    });

    $('.tfctg1').click(function(){
        var na = $(this).text();
        var id = $(this).val();
            
        if(na != 'total' && id != ''){
            // alert(na+'\n'+id);   
            myWindow = window.open("history.php?id="+id, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=300,left=250,width=1000,height=400");         
        }
    });

    $('#infobox').draggable();
});
```

Below is HTML

```
echo "<td id='rat' class='rtio' value='ctr|".$clstr[$t]."|".$x."|".$c."' title='".$clstr[$t]."|".$x."|".$c."'>";    
                    echo ${'rat'.$c}[$t][$x];
                    $csv .= ${'rat'.$c}[$t][$x].",";
                    ${'sum_wip_'.$x} += ${'rat'.$c}[$t][$x];
                echo "</td>";
```

Below is in history.php page

```
$var = explode("|", $_GET['id']); // ctr|".$clstr[$t]."|".$x."|".$c."
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML

Comment: Any chance Edge is configured to prevent JavaScript execution, or its blocking this particular script from running? 
  Does the page load correctly in other Chromium based web browsers such as Opera or Chrome?

Comment: @RickyMo I've added the codes

Comment: @nigh_anxiety I think in all modern browsers including Chrome because data didn't pass out in these modern browsers. But in IE it's running smoothly.

Comment: @RickyMo i'm causing another JS error when I click. can you please kindly check and help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640382/causing-uncaught-typeerror-document-hwinv-datatyp-options-focus-is-not-a-functi?noredirect=1#comment128313712_72640382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td>` does not intend to contain a `value` attribute, and hence cannot be retrieved by `val()` using jquery. Maybe IE engine is so sloppy that it allow this unintended behaviour.

Use [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) for retrieving general attributes.

```
var id = $(this).prop("value");
```

Or better use a [data-* attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) for custom data field to avoid confusion.

HTML

```
echo "<td id='rat' class='rtio' data-id='ctr|".$clstr[$t]."|".$x."|".$c."' title='".$clstr[$t]."|".$x."|".$c."'>";
```

JS

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

Comment: should i use prop("value") or .data("id")?

Comment: Either should work, but I would recommend using `data-` for custom data field instead of using an unintended attribute.

Comment: Nvm, i read carefully and understood ur explanation. Thanks for ur help.